# JavaScript: how do I use binary search to find numbers in a sorted array within a given range

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary-search

I am trying to write a function to return a subset of a sorted input array where all the numbers are within the input range. For example:

```js
getNumsWithin([1,2,3,5,6,7], [3.3, 6.7]) // [5, 6]
getNumsWithin([1,2,3,5,6,7], [6, 7]) // [6, 7]
getNumsWithin([1,2,3,5,6,7], [8, 10]) // []
```

Given the input array is always sorted, I assume I can use binary search to find a start index and an end index and just slice the original array with them.

Here is my attempt:

```js
function findStartIdx(sortedArray, target) {
  let start = 0,
    end = sortedArray.length - 1

  while (start < end) {
    const mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2)
    if (sortedArray[mid] < target) start = mid
    else end = mid - 1
  }

  return start + 1
}

function findEndIdx(sortedArray, target) {
  let start = 0,
    end = sortedArray.length - 1

  while (start < end) {
    const mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2)
    if (sortedArray[mid] < target) start = mid + 1
    else end = mid
  }

  return end + 1
}

function getNumsWithin(array, range) {
  const startIndex = findStartIdx(array, range[0])
  const endIndex = findEndIdx(array, range[1])

  return array.slice(startIndex, endIndex + 1)
}
```

But the binary search would end up being a endless loop if the target happens to the last num in the array. Also I wonder if we can just search it once instead of twice to find both the start and the

I am struggling to write such a function. can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is fine, but the binary search functions need some changes:

- The `while` condition should allow `start` and `end` to be equal.
- The comparison of `target` in the second version should be different so that equal values are *included* in the final range.

Here is a correction of both:

```
function findStartIdx(sortedArray, target) {
  let start = 0,
    end = sortedArray.length - 1

  while (start <= end) {
    const mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2)
    if (sortedArray[mid] < target) start = mid + 1
    else end = mid - 1
  }

  return start
}

function findEndIdx(sortedArray, target) {
  let start = 0,
    end = sortedArray.length - 1

  while (start <= end) {
    const mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2)
    if (sortedArray[mid] <= target) start = mid + 1
    else end = mid - 1
  }

  return end
}
```

On a final note: in terms of time complexity it would be fine to only perform one binary search, and then continue with a linear search through the array. This is because taking the slice represents the same time complexity as searching the end of the slice with a linear search: both are O(slicesize). But given that in JavaScript the `slice` method is *fast* compared to a more "manual" linear search with an explicit loop, you'll get better results with these two binary searches.

Comment: thanks! could you maybe add the code snippet that incorporates the optimization you mentioned at the end?

Comment: I think you misunderstand. Your algorithm idea with 2 binary searches is fine. There is no optimisation. I merely pointed to an alternative that has the same time complexity, but for large arrays would perform *worse* because of the tools that JavaScript offers.

Comment: got it thanks! is there a way to find the start and end index using one binary search pass instead of two separate searches?

Comment: No, ... well, you can combine them in one function, but essentially you'll still do 2 binary searches. Nothing to worry about. When you do one binary search, it doesn't increase the time complexity to do a second one.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to make sure `findStartIdx` works, then the rest is easy. So instead of looking for exact match as in normal [binary search](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-in-javascript/), we look for a match between two numbers at index `mid` and `mid + 1`.

Edge cases: haven't tested if same numbers appear multiple times. Need to fix `findEndIdx` a bit.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
var start = 0
var end = arr.length - 1;

console.log(getNumsWithin(arr, [3.3, 6.7]))
console.log(getNumsWithin(arr, [6, 7]))
console.log(getNumsWithin(arr, [8, 10]))

function findStartIdx(sortedArray, x, start, end) {
  if (start > end) return -1;
  let mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
  if (arr[mid] <= x) {
    if (mid === arr.length - 1) {
      return mid;
    }
    if (arr[mid + 1] >= x) return mid;
    return findStartIdx(sortedArray, x, mid + 1, end);
  } else {
    return findStartIdx(sortedArray, x, start, mid - 1);
  }
}

// hehe
function findEndIdx(sortedArray, x, start, end) {
  var result = findStartIdx(sortedArray, x, start, end) + 1
  if (result == sortedArray.length) return -1;
  return result;
}


function getNumsWithin(array, range) {
  const startIndex = findStartIdx(array, range[0], start, end)
  const endIndex = findEndIdx(array, range[1], start, end)
  if (startIndex == -1 || endIndex == -1) {
    return [];
  }
  return array.slice(startIndex, endIndex + 1)
}
```